# All urls in css files are mistranslated for some reason

Tags: css, image, url

I got a very strange problem with my website. It happens randomly Let me take an example of the main CSS file from my website

```
http://www.xxxxx.net/oxwall/ow_static/plugins/base/css/ow.css
```

which defines background image for alot of widget, for example

ow_console_lang_ai{background:url(images/flags/AI.png)

this one is correctly located at

```
http://www.xxxxxx.net/oxwall/ow_static/plugins/base/css/images/flags/AI.png
```

At runtime, ow.css is included by every single pages. **And most of the time**, things go smoothly, but sometime, (just sometime!!) all urls messed up. All images (by all, it is around 200-400 images) is appended to the resquesting url.

For examples: this one **/oxwall/photo/useralbum/EltonJohn/109** may trigger 200+ requests of of wrong urls from ow.css:

/oxwall/photo/useralbum/EltonJohn/**images/flags/GT.png**

The number of images is huge that occupies all available process of my preforked Apache..

I have been googling for days. I thought it was mod_deflate but no... Any idea?

Comment: UPDATE: Oh, and it only happens when I am behind my corporate firewall

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a slash:

Old code:

```
ow_console_lang_ai{background:url(images/flags/AI.png)
```

New code:

```
ow_console_lang_ai{background:url(/images/flags/AI.png)
```

Comment: no, not working ! It became something uglier: http://www.xxxxxx.net/images/flags/AI.png

Answer (score 0):

Some you're sayin' when you write this `/oxwall/photo/useralbum/EltonJohn/109` it's searching `/oxwall/photo/useralbum/EltonJohn/images/flags/GT.png` ? I'm not sure to understand

EDIT :

So i was thinking, if you call your css as before , but before your file you can externalize your specific class and put your relative url in javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <style>
        .box {
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var url = location.href;
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="test-image box"></div>


<script>
        document.write('<style>                                 \
                        .test-image {                           \
                            background-image:url('+url+');      \
                        }                                       \
                        </style>');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is not a best idea , but hope this help

Allan

Comment: Yes, because /oxwall/photo/useralbum/EltonJohn/109 includes ow.css which has url(images/flags/GT.png) inside it...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is not the code but the picture.
Once I had a image that has a ".PNG"-ending and not ".png"-ending and my website doesn't load it.